# How can I render backtick HTML string in my gmail using Node js or Nodemailer

Tags: nodemailer

**
I created a contact page using Nodemailer(npm package) to get email from client. This is the structure {{--! `Name: <b> ${fullName}</b> </br> Gmail: ${clientEmail} </br> ${text} </br> Sincerely Yours, </br> <b> ${fullName}</b>.` --}. After sending my text in Gmail, This html code does not rendering.
Now, how can I fix it please answer me

This was my mail :

[image]

Here is my full code
**

```
 router.post("/contact" , (req,res)=>{
try {
  
    let fromMail="bjrprogamer@gmail.com"
    let toMail="bjrprogamer@gmail.com"
    let sub="BJR Weather Forecast"
    let text=req.body.message
    let clientEmail=req.body.email
    let fullName=req.body.name
   
   const mailoption= {
     from:fromMail,
     to:toMail,
     subject:sub,
     text:`Name: <b> ${fullName}</b> </br> Gmail: ${clientEmail} </br> ${text} </br> Sincerely Yours, </br> <b> ${fullName}</b>.`
   }
   mailer.transporter.sendMail(mailoption , (err,res)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }else{
      console.log(res)
    }
   });
   res.send("Mail send Succesfully")

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
   
  });
```